# How to "Execute arbitrary PHP script" in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, bulk-operations

I have been trying to make changes to some fields in my library project. I want to update the count of books on it's return. The return of book is implemented using bulk operation.

How can I make changes in the other content types using arbitrary php script? Is there any prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the right drupal hook.

I'm going to need more information before I can help you find the correct hook.

Do you have link we can look at?

Is this a views (module) page?

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by using node presave to the content type 'book' where the count of books get updated.